# JavaScript Help regarding adjusting/delaying Function timings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

First and foremost, everything I say is only applicable for mobile version of my website - https://wtstest1.weebly.com so while troubleshooting please use the mobile view.

Secondly I have included the particular JavaScript ( Jquery ) codes relevant to the subject for your reference:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  var wW = $(window).width();
  $(document).off('click','.wsite-menu-item');
  $(document).on('click','.wsite-menu-item', function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var _href = _this.attr('href');
    var _top;
    if(wW > 992){
      _top = $(_href).offset().top - 64;
      $('body').removeClass('nav-open')
    }else{
      _top = $(_href).offset().top - 50;
      $('body').removeClass('nav-open')
      $('.boo_onepage').removeClass('show')
    }
    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:_top},500)
  })
```

When you will load my website in mobile view, you will find a arrow at top having some options, tapping on each of them scrolls to particular sections within my webpage. 
Although the arrow didn't minimized on its own after an option was tapped which was inconvenient hence I added the second last line you can see in code:

```
$('.boo_onepage').removeClass('show')
```

Now adding this line made the arrow to minimize on its own when a option was chosen

**But it lead to another issue - my main reason of posting this.........**

Now The arrow minimizes on its own after chosing an option but it happens way too quickly and in the process it skips the active-tab/hover effect which was there originally. 
It helped to let the user know where they have tapped by displaying the tab in yellow color for like close to less than 1 second then proceeded to scroll to requested section.

Can someone adjust the jQuery code to make the arrow minimize on its own after choosing an option and still retaining the active tab/hover effect.

What I tried from my end - I tried using `setTimeout(function()` to delay function - `$('.boo_onepage').removeClass('show')` by 1 second but it didn't work as well as expected.

( In case someone wants to see how adding that line made the arrow to minimize on its own but removed the hover/active option effect, you can check it here - https://wtstest.weebly.com )

Answer (score 0):

I had read your post...!
You can follow my code below

```
// When click arrow navbar it's increase size follow 1s
$(document).on('click','.boo_onepage_toggle', function(){
  $('.boo_onepage_menu').css({'font-size':'20px','transition':'1s'})
})
// When choose one option the arrow will decrease size follow 1s
// The user when navigation to arrow It's screen point similar button for user understand "Click"
$(document).on('click','.wsite-menu-item', function(){
  $('.boo_onepage_menu').css({'font-size':'10px','cursor':'pointer','transition':'1s'})
  $('.boo_onepage').removeClass('show')
})
// Hover when user move to arrow
$('.boo_onepage_menu').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css({'font-size':'20px','cursor':'pointer','transition':'1s'})
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css({'font-size':'10px','cursor':'pointer','transition':'1s'})
})
```

Have a nice day...!

Comment: Thanks for replying firsly.  I tried your code and added it my website although it didn't producted the desired effect.    Website with your JavaScript codes having output like this - https://wtsshoptrial.weebly.com

Comment: you can add code inside function .wsite-menu-item. After click menu item it's hidden menubar

    $('.boo_onepage').removeClass('show')

Comment: i am using your code like this - https://del.dog/uvulimokis.htm  . sorry i might be wrong , not familiar at all with javascript     ( the jquery codes present in my question was given by someone elsle )               on another note , i see that your code is dealing with changing size of the arrow , i actually wanted a hover/active effect which you can check here https://wtstest1.weebly.com/

Comment: Ok man...!
Have you want when user hover at arrow. It's increase size and else ?

I fixed width my code. You can test it